# Asking for specific custom implementations?

Tags: discussion, scope, questions

Would you deem a question like (highly simplified)

> *Did anybody implement [a specific function/algorithm] in the PostgreSQL/**PostGIS** environment [or know of someone who did/shares a
>   code-base]?*

acceptable for GIS.SE, provided sufficient information on research/availability on the problem, and the **clear distinction to *Software Recommendations*** (i.e. knowing exactly what other software provides support)?

---

I did an exhaustive search on a specific (GIS-related) problem and tried to locate any custom implementation for *PostGIS* with no result, and before starting to implement that myself I'd like to ask the community e.g. if I have overseen anything on the common repository hubs etc.

Asking this on GIS.SE seems natural, but I think I'm wrong here...

Comment: thx Andre, and thx @PolyGeo: I thought so myself and would have answered the same here I guess; I made a last tiny edit (changed a word or two) to possibly clarify why I asked this here (the absence of any developement, despite my hardest efforts to locate one), but I think I'll try going to the chat, with details of that problem (I left it out here intentionally)...and to implement that set of algorithms myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a question like this is too broad for focused Q&A because there may be many people who have done this or know of someone who has done it.  Consequently, such a question is likely to attract multiple answers, some of which may be detailed but others likely to be a list of low quality offerings like:

> I think Prof. X at University Y has done this but I am not totally familiar with her work so you could contact her direct.

Such a question could also be closed for seeking code without providing a code attempt.  Even non-working code is helpful because it not only shows us what you have tried and where you are stuck, but it may contain ideas like new coding patterns for visitors grappling with a similar issue.

A focused question which should attract a smaller number of higher quality answers could be:

> I am trying to implement [a specific function/algorithm].
>
> I am using the code below but when I run it I get this error (or this unexpected result).
>
> How can I get past where I am stuck?

An alternative to asking an unfocused question on the Main site would be to pose it in the [GIS Chat Room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/939/gis) instead.